Permission denied to ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
I'm trying to alter the default privileges of a role (roleB) that I am a member of, to allow it to modify objects created by another role (roleA) that I am also a member of.
I have the inherit attribute set on my role.
This is on a PostgreSQL 16 instance in Azure (Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server).
Example errors:
Cannot execute SQL
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE "roleA" REVOKE ALL ON SEQUENCES FROM "roleB";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE "roleA" GRANT USAGE,UPDATE,SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO "roleB";

permission denied to change default privileges

If your current user is a member of "roleA", these statements will succeed. Perhaps you are using a modified version of PostgreSQL? Note that the statements might not do what you want, since they don't affect objects created by "roleB".

@LaurenzAlbe I mixed up the order of roles I believe. Edited that now, thanks! The database is on an Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server but I don't believe that should make any difference.

Well, then the case is simple: you must be a member of "roleA" (or a superuser) to run that statement. That the database is on Azure is significant. All hosting providers have hacked up PostgreSQL one way or the other, and that often affects permissions.

Interesting. I'm a member of both roles (with admin) but still can't get this to work. I haven't found any Azure specific documentation of this behaviour but I guess I'll keep looking and create a support request as well.

Just a sanity check: those backslashes are not really in your SQL statement, are they?

They are not. Edited again.
